# Azure devops Cant connect Nuget Restore and VSBuild for Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a very basic build pipeline so far

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- testing-build-yml-1

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    # packagesDirectory: '..\packages'
    restoreDirectory: '..\new_packages'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    #msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:ReferencePath="d:\a\1\new_packages"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I am trying to the Nuget Restore task to get packages restored to `..\new_packages` directory and subsequently hoping that the VSBuild Task will get them from there and build the solution.

The Nuget Restore executes the following command (all in one line)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin\msbuild.exe 
  "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\jgtjjpe0.nac.nugetinputs.targets" 
  /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile 
   /nologo 
   /nr:false 
   /v:q 
  /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\whba0xm4.c0f.nugetrestore.targets" 
  /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets="True" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.4.0\x64\nuget.exe" 
  /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="D:\a\1\s\\" 
  /p:RestoreConfigFile="D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_105.config" 
  /p:RestorePackagesPath="..\new_packages" 
  /p:SolutionDir="D:\a\1\s\\" 
  /p:SolutionName="XYZ"
```

Then VSBuild Task runs msbuild (all in one line)

```
##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" 
 "D:\a\1\s\XYZ.sln" 
   /nologo 
   /nr:false 
   /dl:CentralLogger,
 "D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.161.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";
 "RootDetailId=e5869970-8e7b-4a06-a8fd-f0662f639a6d|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.161.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
 /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
 /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
 /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
 /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
 /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\1\a" 
 /p:ReferencePath="d:\a\1\new_packages" 
 /p:platform="Any CPU" 
 /p:configuration="Release" 
 /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0" 
 /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_607486bc-2d64-463d-9a7f-0cf06fe82263_build_16_0"
```

The solution looks at the appropriate directory as specified in the `/p:ReferencePath="d:\a\1\new_packages`.

But it still can't find any dlls for the Nuget packages and ultimately the build fails.

```
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 1/9/2020 10:11:18 PM.
Project "D:\a\1\s\XYZ.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
Project "D:\a\1\s\XYZ.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\ServiceLayer\InputOutputServiceLayer.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "EPPlus, Version=4.5.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EPPlus, Version=4.5.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EPPlus, Version=4.5.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\ServiceLayer\InputOutputServiceLayer.csproj]
          For SearchPath "d:\a\1\new_packages".
          Considered "d:\a\1\new_packages\EPPlus.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "d:\a\1\new_packages\EPPlus.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "d:\a\1\new_packages\EPPlus.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "D:\a\1\s\packages\EPPlus.4.5.3.2\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

Technically, I know we're not supposed to hardcode a `/p:ReferencePath=..` do this but I'm just trying to get it to work.

Without that VSBuild Task seems to have no idea where to even look.

It looks at

```
 ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "EPPlus, Version=4.5.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EPPlus, Version=4.5.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EPPlus, Version=4.5.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\ServiceLayer\InputOutputServiceLayer.csproj]
          For SearchPath "..\d:\a\1\a".
          Considered "..\d:\a\1\a\EPPlus.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "..\d:\a\1\a\EPPlus.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "..\d:\a\1\a\EPPlus.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "d:\a\1\s\packages\EPPlus.4.5.3.2\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\EPPlus.winmd", but it didn't exist.
```

There is a similar question using the old way of using the pipeline

[MsBuild does not find restored NuGet-Packages on Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287852/msbuild-does-not-find-restored-nuget-packages-on-visual-studio-online)

Their solution (though hacky) doesn't work for me either.

If I remove the EPPlus package, the next package `Entity Framework` will produce the same errors.
If I remove `Entity Framework` the next package will produce the same errors.

I'm just trying to find a real solution for this which doesn't involve these hardcoding hacks (..and works, obviously)

**EDIT:**

Working, with quirks thanks to `Leo Liu-MSFT`.
My answer is below that one.

Comment: We faced a very similar problem and in our case it was solved by explicitly referencing an extra layer deep where the project file lives; in theory that shouldn't have been needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure devops Cant connect Nuget Restore and VSBuild for Nuget Packages

I am afraid you could not make it work unless you modify the `HintPath` in your project file.

When you change the nuget packages restored to `..\new_packages` directory, after restore, the package in the new directory should have following structural levels:

```
d:\a\1\new_packages\EPPlus.4.5.3.2\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll
```

**The dll file is stored in your new directory in the form of a nuget package, rather than directly in the new directory.**

So, when you specify the `/p:ReferencePath="d:\a\1\new_packages"` during building the project, VS will find the `dll` file directly from the `ReferencePath`. That the reason why you get the error message is:

> Considered "d:\a\1\new_packages\EPPlus.dll"

Actually, the `dll` path should be `d:\a\1\new_packages\EPPlus.4.5.3.2\lib\net40`. Since this path is related to both the name and version of the package, we could not use one parameter to specify the path of multiple `dlls`.

In this case, we have to modify the `HintPath` in the project file.

The correct process is that change the repositoryPath in the `nuget.config` file to change the nuget package directory on your local:

[Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)

then use command line `Update-Package -reinstall` in the Package Manager Console to force reinstall the package references into project **on your local**, it will update the `HintPath` for all packages, then submit the changes to the source control. Then we could use the Nuget Restore task to get packages restored to `..\new_packages` directory

Hope this helps.

Comment: nuget.config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>

Comment: build yml with or without the `restoreDirectory: '..\packages'` or ` '.\packages' `

Comment: UPDATE -- all the projects using the `<PackageRefrence>` instead of `packages.config` are working. The `MVC WebClient` is hard due to preinstalled MS-libraries /packages

Comment: it keeps creating a temp nuget config file even though i keep specifying where to look

Comment: I got it working, I deleted everything in the packages folder and pushed. It forced azure to download and restore and somehow helped with the build. I put more details below

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work but with a few quirks (and features?) and few pending questions.

Please see `/users/7460777/leo-liu-msft` above to get some context as to why some of these steps are taken.

As Leo mentioned this has to do with the `HintPath` not being updated properly in the projects that use `packages.config`

To avoid this issue altogether,
migrate as many projects as possible to the `<PackageReference />` instead of using `packages.config`. To do this, right click on the `References` inside each project, there should be an option to do so.
Some projects (E.g -> in my case, my asp.net (.net Framework) MVC Web Client) can't be migrated.
(..I'll add more details i found on this later)
**UPDATE:**
(https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/)
(https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5877)

---

Next Steps:--

1) On the top level folder where I have the `.sln` file, I created the following `nuget.config`file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Since my `packages` directory is here.

2) My updated `build.yml`is below.

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- testing-build-yml

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    packagesdirectory: '.\packages'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

3) **The following step caused everything to work, but Im still unsure why exactly.**
I deleted everything inside the `packages` folder and basically just pushed those deletions upstream.
Nuget restore Task did a restore and the VSBuild task succeeded.

---

Things I'm still unsure of --

1) Why is a temporary `Nuget.config` file created even though I clearly said where it exists?

```
Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.4.0\x64\nuget.exe sources Add -NonInteractive -Name NuGetOrg -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -ConfigFile d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_140.config
Package source with Name: NuGetOrg added successfully.
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.4.0\x64\nuget.exe restore d:\a\1\s\XYZ.sln -PackagesDirectory .\packages -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_140.config
NuGet Version: 5.4.0.6315
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.4.0.56107' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin\msbuild.exe 
"C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\0eie04ka.4ch.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\y3ui4hhz.gfr.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets="True" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.4.0\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="d:\a\1\s\\" /p:RestoreConfigFile="d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_140.config" /p:RestorePackagesPath=".\packages" /p:SolutionDir="d:\a\1\s\\" /p:SolutionName="XYZ"
```

2) Why does deleting packages make it work while committing the packages make it unable to find any dll files even though it looks at the correct places?

```
Primary reference "NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\XYZ_WebClient\XYZ_WebClient.csproj]
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "D:\a\1\s\packages\NLog.4.6.7\lib\net45\NLog.dll", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\NLog.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\NLog.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\NLog.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\NLog.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\NLog.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\NLog.exe", but it didn't exist.
```